# Translate Scala connection to Azure DW to PySpark

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to update a table at ADW but the only path I have found so far to do so is through scala, which I'm not very familiar with, and I would like to have the same functionality with PySpark.

This is the scala code, but I'm stucked trying to translate it

```
import java.util.Properties
import java.sql.DriverManager

val jdbcUsername = "xxxxx"
val jdbcPassword = "xxxxx"
val driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

val jdbcUrl = s"xxxx"

val connectionProperties = new Properties()

connectionProperties.put("user", s"${jdbcUsername}")
connectionProperties.put("password", s"${jdbcPassword}")
connectionProperties.setProperty("Driver", driverClass)

val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword)
val stmt = connection.createStatement()
val sql = "delete from table where condition"

stmt.execute(sql)
connection.close()
```

I think there must be a general way to execute commands on Azure SQL using PySpark, but I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to directly do the delete operation on a table of Azure SQL Database in Python for Azure Databricks, but I tried to realize it failed because there is no way to install linux odbc driver for `pyodbc` and `pymssql`.

Here is few screenshots about my testing.

Fig 1. Successfully installed `pymssql`, `pypyodbc` on Cluster, but failed for `pyodbc`

[image]

Fig 2. Got the issues about missing linux odbc driver when try to connect my Azure SQL Database

[image]

So except using Scala/Java introduced by the offical tutorial [`Use HDInsight Spark cluster to read and write data to Azure SQL database`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-connect-to-sql-database), only a workaround way for using Python is to invoke a webhook url which realize the feature from other Azure services, such as Azure Function in Python.

Comment: Thank you Peter for your answer, and I think you're right, a better workaround would be to work directly using Scala/Java; I was able though to set up the driver and install pyodbc [link] https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/10/12/executing-sql-server-stored-procedures-on-databricks-pyspark.